# Asuras/Rakshasas who became good?

Tags: puranas, asuras, itihasa, rakshasa

There were some Rakshasas like Vibhishana who were noble.
Were there any Asuras/Rakshasas who were initially evil but eventually became good i.e moved to the side of Dharma?

Comment: [Maareecha](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga37/aranya_37_frame.htm) is another one.

Comment: Can you count Mahabali, The anonymous bramharakshas of Nampaduvan at Thirukurungudi & Gadodhgajan in it? @sv AFAIK, Mareecha advised the dharmic way, but didn't move as per the question. Just want to learn by asking questions..

Comment: Well Hidimbi,the wife of Pandava Bhima,is one of them.I heard that due to her penance,she became a goddess.Sachi,wife of Indra,is also another demoness as she was the daughter of Paolouman(I think I spelt the name wrongly),the Asura king.And Mandodari,queen of Rakshasas.

Comment: How are Raakshasa  evil ay first place? You know that even Devas can produce obstruction in tasks, it is called "Deva Badhaa" (obstruction madr by Devas). All Devas and Asuras are initially Dharmic , or evil, or good or bad or enlighten. Even Asuras practice Yoga and Devas play mischief

Comment: @AnuragSingh, if you have ever read Ramayana or Mahabharatha you'll know that Raakshasas often disrupted yajnas & yagas, killed and ate rishis and saadhus. How many Devas indulged in such behavior? Please keep your 'postmodernist' thinking out.

Comment: Yes and if you read Scriptures you will see how each time Indra produces obstacles for Munis, Vasus stole KaamaDhenu cow, Brihaspati forced his younger brother wife for intercourse, and then curses the baby in womb to be blind, Chandra abducted Taaraa, Brihaspati fooling the Yoga doing Asuras by becoming Shukracharya @Bharat

Answer (score 3):

1)Vibhishana
2)Mahabali
3)Hidimbi
4)Sachi
5)Mandodari
Are there any more?

Comment: Prahlada of course

Comment: Mandodari? Was she even a Raakshasa?

Comment: https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/varanasi/Ravana-was-a-Brahmin-from-Ghaziabad-Subramanian-Swamy/articleshow/45663447.cms                       Ravana and Mandodari from UP, India Brahmins as per above report Subramania swamy.

Comment: Prahlada was an asura, but he was saintly and noble from the first :-)

Answer (score 3):

### Asuras/Rakshasas/Daityas/Danavas who were initially evil but eventually became good i.e moved to the side of Dharma?

- **Hidimva** or **Hidimbi** or **Hidimbā**

> She is mentioned as the female cannibal in [The Mahabharata, Book 1: Adi Parva: Hidimva-vadha Parva: Section CLIV](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01155.htm).

> But after marrying Bhima she became good. As per this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidimbi#Worship), currently there are a few temples dedicated to Hidimbā Devi.

- **Malyavan**

> Initially, Malyavan (Ravana's maternal grandfather's brother) was king of Lanka. He was not good to the deities, sages, and ascetics. When they complained about Malyavan and other Rakshas to Vishnu, Malyavan attacked on Devas with his brothers Mali and Sumali where Mali was killed by Vishnu and other two left Lanka and started living in Rasatala. Later on Kubera started living in Lanka till Ravana took it from him. -[UTTARA KANDA of Valmiki Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-6)

> But in Rama-Ravana war, Malyavan preaches Ravana. -[Yuddha Kanda - Sarga 35 of Valmiki Ramayana](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga35/yuddha_35_frame.htm)

- **Bāṇāsura**: Story is given in [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) » Canto 10 .63](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/63)
- **Mahishasura**: In his another birth, Mahishasura worshipped Bhadrakali for attain salvation. Kalika Purana was mentioned that.

---

### Asuras/Rakshasas/Daityas/Danavas who were of virtuous nature:

- **Shachi** (queen of Indra), the daughter of Asura Pulaman (as per [Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03182.htm))
- **Bali Maharaj** (as per most of the Puranas)
- **Prahlad** (as per most of the Puranas)
- **Prahoti** (as per [Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-4))
- **Vibhishana** (as per Ramayana)
- **Vajrang**, Diti's son and TARAKASUR's father (as per [Shiva Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/shiva_purana/the_birth_of_vajrang.php))
- **Mandodari**, daughter of Maya Danava (as per [Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-12))

Comment: You should add chapter name because links may be dead some day. It happened many times. Don't worry about some comments saying chapter name is inconsistent. Just add the chapter name you found.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03273.htm

> Brahma then addressed Vibhishana, 'O my son, I am much pleased with thee! Ask any boon thou pleasest!' Thereupon, Vibhishana replied, 'Even in great danger, may I never swerve from the path of righteousness, and though ignorant, may I, O adorable Sire, be illumined with the light of divine knowledge!' And Brahma replied, 'O scourge of thy enemies, as thy soul inclines not to unrighteousness although born in the Rakshasa race, I grant thee immortality!'

Vibhishna asked Brahma that he should always be righteous and have the light of divine knowledge. Brahma was so pleased that in addition, he even bestowed immortality upon him.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious interpretation of the Shiva Purana is Vajrāṅga is an Asura who stopped being evil on his own. However, technically the only verse he is referred to as an Asura could be interpreted as giving up his Asura form.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226078.html
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-sanskrit/d/doc389737.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many. Some of them are as follows.:

- [Andhaka](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc425609.html) became Bhringi.
- [Banasura](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226197.html) became a Shiva Gana though later slain by Goddess Kanya Kumari.
- [3 Sons of Yagna Varaha Vishnu viz Suvrtta, Kanaka, Ghora](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/54995/20968) became 3 sacred fire after their death by Lord Sharabha.
- [Mahabali became Chiranjeevi and Virochana died by giving his head as a charity to Indra.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc365965.html)
- [Prahlada](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26213/20968) later slayed by Indra.
- [Ghatotkach](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/49434/20968) died while saving the life if Arjuna from Karna.
- [Surapadma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9A%C5%ABrapadm%C4%81) became the peacock of Lord Kartikeya.
- [Krauncha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26718/20968) aka Mushakasura became the Mouse of Lord Ganesha.

And so on.

I hope this helps. Prd..

Answer (score 0):

One must have more patience to hear the answer that follows:

```
     BAD CANT ADVICE BAD
```

NEITHER ASURAAS NOR RAAKSHASAAS were/are good. They committed attrocities to such extent that they were driven away from Divine paths in Universe from ages.

Prahlaada or Vibheeshana or others were not ASURA janmaas but MAANAVA janmaas to give last chance to their relatives that "they cannot impact so many living beings on Earth just because they are powerful by unjust ways for which there were no competitors".

To warn Asura, there must be a Maanavas (from whom Manu Dharma originated) to understand Divine qualities & Demonaic bad deeds.