# Did Lord Rama or Lord Krishna ever convince any Rakshasa?

Tags: krishna, rama, life, rakshasa

Did Lord Rama or Lord Krishna ever convince any Rakshasa and also did the Rakshasa changed his attitude to only spiritual life leaving behind all his sinful actions and follow them?

Comment: Do you mean that Rakshasa have to be evil in the beginning? If so please update your Question...else Vibhishana can be the answer...

Comment: Vibhishana was not evil, and neither was he convinced by Rama. He was conscious since the beginning, and was purely Dharmic.

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar When did I say that he was evil.. I am clarifying with the OP.. Anyway Vibhishana was preached by Rama several time..

Comment: Yes you didn't say he was evil, I just added it. And secondly, my point was that since Vibhishana was not evil, like Ravana, or ignorantly aloof like Kumbhakarna, he was Dharmic and needed no preaching to "change" into a Dharmic person. Yes Rama did preach to him, but Vibhishana was pure since the beginning. Ramacharitmanas mentions that Vibhishana's house had paintings of Rama's weapons of war, and a Tulsi plant.

Comment: Related: [Asuras/Rakshasas who became good?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10690/2995)

Answer (score 2):

Rama, Lakshmana and Sita were
exiled for a period of 14 years
from the kingdom by Dasharatha
at the behest of Rama's
stepmother Kaikeyi . The trio
traveled south from Ayodhya and
passed through the
Dandakaranya (Dandaka forest)
to the banks of the Godavari
River where they built a
hermitage at Panchavati .
Maricha recalls the following
incident when talking with
Ravana. However, it does not
appear as a separate event in
the chronological telling of the
Ramayana . Maricha returned to
Dandakaranya and disguised
himself as a beast with a flaming
tongue and two sharp horns. He
was accompanied by two
rakshasas in the form of animals.
They feasted on human flesh and
traveled to pilgrimage sites,
terrorizing ascetics. They would
kill ascetics and drink their
blood. Once, Maricha saw Rama,
Lakshmana and Sita.
Remembering his last encounter,
Maricha attacked them in his
ferocious beast form to seek
vengeance with his demonic
companions. Rama shot three
arrows at once, killing Maricha's
allies, but the third arrow
narrowly missed Maricha, who
fled in fear.
The spared Maricha was
transformed into a saintly
person. He lived a life of an
ascetic. He set up an ashram,
grew matted hair and wore tree
bark. He continued living there
out of the fear of Rama

Source:— [Valmiki ramayana](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga39/aranya_39_frame.htm)

> एवम् अस्मि तदा मुक्तः कथंचित्
>   तेन संयुगे |
>   इदानीम् अपि यत् वृत्तम् तत्
>   शृउणुष्व यत् उत्तरम् ||
>   ४-३९-१
>
> "Thus I was somehow
>   released by him in a
>   confrontation then in his
>   teens. Now you may also listen
>   to what has happened later in
>   his adulthood." Thus
>   Maareecha continued his
>   advise to Ravana. [4-39-1]
>
> राक्षाभ्याम् अहम् द्वाभ्याम्
>   अनिर्विण्णः तथा कृतः |
>   सहितो मृग रूपाभ्याम् प्रविष्टो
>   दँडका वने || ४-३९-२
>
> "Though Rama hit me
>   previously in such a way, I
>   unabashedly entered Dandaka
>   forest together with two more
>   demons who were in the guise
>   of animals. [4-39-2]
>
> दीप्त जिह्वो महादंष्ट्रः तीक्ष्ण
>   शृंगो महाबलः |
>   व्यचरन् दँडाकारण्यम् मांस
>   भक्षो महामृगः || ४-३९-३
>
> "On becoming a
>   gigantic carnivorous animal
>   with a torching tongue,
>   incisive teeth and excruciating
>   horns, and with an
>   extraordinary energy, I was on
>   the rove in Dandaka forest
>   while getting at Rama. [4-39-3]
>
> अग्निहोत्रेषु तीर्थेषु चैत्य
>   वृक्षेषु रावण |
>   अत्यन्त घोरो व्यचरन् तापसान्
>   संप्रधर्षयन् || ४-३९-४
>
> "I moved about
>   Dandaka forest, oh, Ravana, in
>   an extremely horrible aspect of
>   animal, utterly brutalising the
>   sages at ritual-altars, holy
>   bathing places and under the
>   trees of religious sanctuaries
>   while reaching Rama. [4-39-4]
>
> निहत्य दँडकारण्ये तापसान्
>   धर्मचरिणः |
>   रुधिराणि पिबन्तः तेषाम् तन्
>   मांसानि च भक्षयन् || ४-३९-५
>
> "I have proceeded to
>   Rama killing saints in Dandaka
>   forest who are the treaders in
>   saintliness, and drinking off
>   their blood and feasting on
>   their flesh. [4-39-5]
>
> ऋषि माअंस अशनः क्रूरः
>   त्रासयन् वनगोचरान् |
>   तदा रुधिर मत्तो अहम् व्यचरन्
>   दँडका वनम् || ४-३९-६
>
> "On becoming such a
>   brutal animal I have been
>   eating the flesh of sages,
>   frightening the forest dwellers,
>   and in that way I rambled in
>   Dandaka forest besotted with
>   blood-drinking while reaching
>   Rama. [4-39-6]
>
> तदा अहम् दँडकारण्ये विचरन्
>   धर्म दूषकः |
>   आसादयम् तदा रामम् तापसम्
>   धर्मम् आश्रितम् || ४-३९-७
>   वैदेहि च महाभागाम् लक्ष्मणम् च
>   महरथम् |
>
> "While I was
>   wandering in Dandaka forest
>   as an abuser of virtue, then I
>   reached Rama who by then has
>   assumed the rectitude befitting
>   to a saint, and I even reached
>   the great-fortunate Vaidehi and
>   top-speeded-chariot-rider
>   Lakshmana. [4-39-7, 8a]
>
> तापसम् नियत आहारम् सर्व बूत
>   हिते रतम् || ४-३९-८
>   सः अहम् वन गतम् रामम् परिभूय
>   महाबलम् |
>   तापसो अयम् इति ज्ञात्वा पूर्व
>   वैरम् अनुस्मरन् || ४-३९-९
>   अभ्यधावम् सुसंक्रुद्धः तीक्ष्ण
>   शृंगो मृग आकृतिः |
>   जिघांसुः अकृतप्रज्ञः तम्
>   प्रहारम् अनुस्मरन् || ४-३९-१०
>
> "I was in the shape of
>   an animal with incisive horns.
>   Such as I was I recollected my
>   earlier grudge against that
>   great mighty Rama who takes
>   delight in the welfare of all
>   being, who by then was
>   santlike on a regulated diet
>   and abiding in the forest,
>   whereby I presumed him to be
>   mere hermit. In that way, I
>   was very extremely infuriated
>   to recollect his earlier assault
>   on me, and I indiscriminately
>   dashed towards him, only to
>   kill him, completely
>   disregarding his other
>   faculties. [4-39-8b, 9, 10]
>
> तेन त्यक्ताः त्रयो बाणाः शिताः
>   शत्रु निबर्हणाः |
>   विकृष्य सुमहत् चापम् सुपर्ण
>   अनिल तुल्य गाः || ४-३९-११
>
> "Stringing out his
>   highly magnificent bow Rama
>   then released three
>   excruciating and enemy
>   eliminating arrows which in
>   their egress match the Air-god
>   and the Divine-Eagle Garuda.
>   [4-39-11]
>
> ते बाणा वज्र संकाशाः सुघोरा
>   रक्त भोजनाः |
>   आजग्मुः सहिताः सर्वे त्रयः
>   संनतपर्वणः || ४-३९-१२
>
> "All those three
>   thunderbolt like arrows that
>   have only blood for their
>   board, acutely bent at barbs,
>   and that are highly horrendous
>   have come at us in a
>   coordinated manner. [4-39-12]
>
> पराक्रमज्ञो रामस्य शठो दृष्ट
>   भयः पुरा |
>   समुत्क्रांतः ततः मुक्तः तौ उभौ
>   राक्षसौ हतौ || ४-३९-१३
>
> "As I have earlier seen
>   the fear caused by his arrow I
>   am in the know of Rama's
>   valour, hence I retreated from
>   there trickily and gingerly, but
>   the other two demons were
>   killed. [4-39-13]
>
> शरेण मुक्तो रामस्य कथंचित्
>   प्राप्यजीवितम् |
>   इह प्रव्राजितो युक्तः तापसो
>   अहम् समाहितः || ४-३९-१४
>
> "When I was somehow
>   exempted by the arrow of
>   Rama I regained lifespan, and
>   when that arrow made me to
>   renounce everything like a
>   monk and fled me to this
>   place, the other side of ocean
>   to where you came by your
>   aircraft, here I am living here
>   in a yogic way, self-collectedly
>   like an ascetic. [4-39-14]

Although he was killed later for gelping ravana by changing in form of golden dear and helping ravana.

proof (marichi advicing ravana):—

> तत् श्रुत्वा राक्षसेन्द्रस्य
>   वाक्यम् वाक्य विशारदः |
>   प्रत्युवाच महाप्राज्ञो मारीचो
>   राक्षसेश्वरम् || ३-३७-१
>
> On hearing that idea of
>   the chief of demons Ravana in
>   abducting Seetha, Maareecha, a
>   well-informed one and an
>   articulator spoke to the lord of
>   demons in reply. [3-37-1]
>
> सुलभाः पुरुषा राजन् सततम् प्रिय
>   वादिनः |
>   अप्रियस्य च पथ्यस्य वक्ता
>   श्रोता च दुर्लभः || ३-३७-२
>
> "It will always be easy
>   to get people who talk
>   pleasantly, oh, king, but it is
>   impossible to get them who
>   talk judgementally and give
>   suggestions that may be
>   apparently insipid, but that are
>   recuperative, more so, it is
>   impossible to get listeners of
>   such advises. [3-37-2]
>
> न नूनम् बुध्यसे रामम् महावीर्यम्
>   गुण उन्नतम् |
>   अयुक्त चारः चपलो महेन्द्र
>   वरुण उपमम् || ३-३७-३
>
> "Definitely you do not
>   apperceive Rama who is
>   decidedly dynamic and
>   exaltedly adept, for you are
>   impetuous and desultory in
>   dealing with your spies, but
>   that Rama is identical to the
>   thunderous Mahendra and
>   tempestuous Varuna, the Rain-
>   god. [3-37-3]
>
> अपि स्वस्ति भवेत् तात
>   सर्वेषाम् भुवि रक्षसाम् |
>   अपि रामो न संक्रुद्धः कुर्यात्
>   लोकम् अराक्षसम् || ३-३७-४
>
> "Oh, boy, will there be
>   safety to all demons on earth?
>   Or, that highly enraged Rama
>   will render this world de-
>   demonised! [3-37-4]

— http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga37/aranya_37_frame.htm

Comment: @Swiftpushkar I was looking for them here they are.

Comment: Maricha  is not the right answer..Else why did he help Ravana????.. He is the main cause for Sita''s abduction...

Comment: @YDS I think that Malyavan is a right answer. He opposed Ravana in his abduction of Sita.

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar Malyavan had fight with Vishnu..and he was frightened after his younger brother was killed by Vishnu..But Question is restricted with Rama and Krishna...So Malyavan might not be considered here..If Qn is open for Vishnu and all his avataras and Daityas, Danavas and Rakshasa..then Bali Maharaj is the answer..And Malyavan also..and probably few more.. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10690/asuras-rakshasas-who-became-good/10692#10692

Comment: Yes thats why I put it in the comments. Malyavan was rectified after the fight.

Comment: Wow I never knew of this second sparing of Maricha by Rama, shows how many treasures the Ramayana has...