# What is the story of Prahlada being slain by Indra?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, indra, prahlada

In [Mahabharata, Santi Parva, SECTION XCVIII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a097.htm), it is said by Indra himself that he has slain Prahlada.

> Having slain in battle Jambha, Vritra, Vala, Paka, Satamaya, Virochana, the irresistible Namuchi, Samvara of innumerable illusions, Viprachitti,--all these sons of Diti and Danu, **as also Prahlada**, I myself have become the chief of the celestials.'

[Sanskrit part](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs12099.htm)

> 48 अहं वृत्रं बलं पाकं शतमायं विरॊचनम
>
> दुरावार्यं च नमुचिं नैकमायं च शम्बरम
>
> 49 विप्रचित्तिं च दैतेयं दनॊः पुत्राश च सर्वशः
>
> परह्रादं च निहत्याजौ ततॊ देवाधिपॊ ऽभवम
>
> 50 इत्य एतच छक्र वचनं निशम्य परतिगृह्य च
>
> यॊधानाम आत्मनः सिद्धिम अम्बरीषॊ ऽभिपन्नवान
>
> 48 ahaṃ vṛtraṃ balaṃ pākaṃ śatamāyaṃ virocanam
>        durāvāryaṃ ca namuciṃ naikamāyaṃ ca śambaram
>
> 49 vipracittiṃ ca daiteyaṃ danoḥ putrāś ca sarvaśaḥ
>        prahrādaṃ ca nihatyājau tato devādhipo 'bhavam
>
> 50 ity etac chakra vacanaṃ niśamya pratigṛhya ca
>        yodhānām ātmanaḥ siddhim ambarīṣo 'bhipannavān

So, I want to know why and when Prahlada was slain by Indra? Was he the same Prahlada (son of Hiranyakashipu) or someone else?

Comment: Maybe its a different one. I too have read a source, forget the name. As far as I know, the 2 Prahlads are different.

Comment: Could it be an error in interpretation? Could he be referring to sons of Diti, Danu and also (of) Prahlad since Virochan is included in the list?

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal May be but not sure.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Please add if the corresponding Sanskrit Slokhas are available... I can't able to find them here http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs12098.htm

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani निहत्याजौ means **after killing**?

Comment: @hanugm That line can be break as `prahrāda ca nihan āji tatas deva adhipa bhū`. Please check the details by clicking on that line [here](http://www.sanskrit-linguistics.org/dcs/index.php?contents=texte&IDTextDisplay=154)

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani: Kurma Purana says Prahlada alongwith his brothers fought with Vishnu. ( https://archive.org/stream/ShivaPurana/Kurma%20Purana_djvu.txt ).  So Original character of Prahlada might have been described as a pure Daitya.  This character might have been converted into a devotee in Bhagavata Purana.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Yes, Nara-Narayana fighting with Prahlada is also mentioned in Harivamsa purana too.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani: So Original character of Prahlada might have been described as a pure Daitya. This character might have been converted into a devotee in Bhagavata Purana.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Its not only Bhagavata. Prahlada as a devotee is mentioned in many scriptures as Vishnu Purana, Shiva Purana, Devi Bhagavata, Mahabharata etc too

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani: Then the question of another Prahlada may not arise.  The same Prahlada, who was depicted in Mahabharata as slain by Indra, had been depicted in some Puranas as a devotee of Vishnu.  It does indicate that those Puranas were written later to Mahabharata.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv You may be right or may be a translation issue.

Comment: Can anyone say the meaning of निहत्याजौ?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani I strongly believe that the slokha may mean Indra defeated Prahlada because at some other places in Mahabharata he did not mentioned killing of Prahlada but other danavas....

**I have banished the Kalakeyas to the earth, and removed the Danavas from heaven, and have terminated the existence of Prahlada in heaven**. http://en.krishnakosh.org/krishna/Mahabharata_Aswamedha_Parva_Chapter_9:3

Comment: @hanugm Yes, I also believe in that. I think we have to look into alternate translation of this text.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Yeah.

Comment: Indra taken away all the things from Prahalada. This may be due to Indra's such winning over Prahlada. Read the story from [MB. Shanti Parva, 124th Chapter](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a123.htm)