# Marriage between Rakhsasas/Asuras and Devas

Tags: gods, marriage, asuras

What are well known instances from Hindu Mythology of marriages between groups of mythical times described as Rakhsasas/Asuras (common guru Shukracharya) versus Devas ?

Have natural change of attitude due to conservatism or sect egos been generally met with social acceptance? Did they face outcasting, disapproval, ostracism etc as time went by? Did a fire of revenge or intense dislike pervade overcoming forgivance that time naturally brings about?

I ask this as they are otherwise often depicted as inherently different genetic/chemical natured belligerent adversaries, one group generally  being of piety character and the other as predominantly of evil even though they are said to share an ancient common Kashyapa lineage.

Query is whether marriages were in general less common due to  enmity that came from advice of uncompromising elder clan members or due to chromosomal  driven attitudes that comes to front in wealth sharing /creation.. that conflict with respected modes of Dharma or its interpretation.. or as YDS points out there have been some singular/notable exceptions (Indra/Sachi, Puloma's daughter) that got accepted by powerful violators ...?

Comment: "What are well known instances from Hindu Mythology?" -- of what? marriage bw Rakshasa and Danvas/Daityas...or marriage bw Danavas/Daityas/Rakshasas and Devas..

Comment: I meant the latter grouping, as these non-Devas are described to be a group of non-sattviks.

Comment: Indra married Shachi, the daughter of an Asura Puloma...

Comment: OK, query whether marriages were in general less common, whether enmity existed so no matrimonial alliances etc..

Comment: pls edit ur Q accordingly..

Comment: I edited but shall make further changes keeping any suggestion in mind about how I should ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few instances:

```
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|          Asuras          |        Devas, Rishis, Apsaras         |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Hoti                     | Yama's sister Bhaya                   |
| Shachi                   | Indra                                 |
| Vidyutkesa               | Sandhya's daugther Salakatmakata      |
| Sukesa                   | Gandharva Gramani's daughter Devavati |
| Malyavanta, Sumali, Mali | Gandharvi Narmada's 3 daughters       |
| Vibhishana               | Gandharva Sailusha's daughter Sarama  |
| Kaikasi                  | Visrava                               |
| Maya                     | Apsara Hema                           |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

**Asuras**: Daityas, Danavas, Rakshasas

**Devas**: Adityas, Gandharvas, Yakshas

---

Refrences:

[Who are Yakshas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8335/who-are-yakshas/22925#22925)

[Asuras/Rakshasas who became good?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10690/asuras-rakshasas-who-became-good/24004#24004)

Comment: Can you add a reference / time column in the table you gave?

Comment: reference is given at the end of the answer..anyway it's from Valmiki Ramayana..time is before or during Ramayana period..

Comment: Chapter number in a column table for record at one place. Even now the appellation Rakshas refers to a person of cruel temperament /character/demeanor.